# What was the urine joke all about?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-sniper

I read this [comic](http://www.awkwardzombie.com/index.php?page=0&comic=072511) about Team Fortress 2, but I did not get the joke.
What was in the bottle? Urine? if so, what's the point of the last panel? why is the spy consoling the sniper?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a comic strip, not a video game or it's content.

Comment: ..my apologies, but isn't team Fortress a video game?

Comment: Sure. And this question isn't about the video game, it's about this comic strip. Last I checked, Diablo tie-in novels, Sonic the Hedgehog Fanfiction, and the old Super Matio Bros. Super Show (RIP Captain Lou!) are all off topic as well.

Comment: I see, my apologies. Please feel free to close the question.
Where should this questions be askedm, btw?

Comment: Maybe at http://scifi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The piss is red/brown, which means the sniper is either pissing blood or he has stool in his urine, which both means he's quite sick/dying, hence the consoling.

Comment: HA!  Can't believe I didn't get that. MArking as accepted

Comment: This question became unexpectedly depressing pretty quickly.

Answer (score 4):

The bottle is the snipers [jarate](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Jarate) throwing weapon, which contains his urine.

Since it's red, he might have a [severe illness](http://www.nhs.uk/conditions/blood-in-urine/Pages/Introduction.aspx).